# Trouble installing QuickUMLS

Tags: python, nlp, medical

I am trying to install QuickUMLS in python 3.7 (Ubuntu OS) for medical NLP. I followed the step by step installation guide provided by this website link -

https://github.com/Georgetown-IR-Lab/QuickUMLS

However after completing the installation, I am not able to instantiate the matcher object using QuickUMLS() command. The following error message pops up.

```
matcher = QuickUMLS(quickumls_fp='/home/dileep/QuickUMLS')

----------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-2c04f59d4b93> in <module>
----> 1 matcher = QuickUMLS(quickumls_fp='/home/dileep/QuickUMLS')

NameError: name 'QuickUMLS' is not defined
```

Am I missing something here? Please help.

Since there was no pip installation involved or specified in the guide, I also tried

```
pip install https://github.com/Georgetown-IR-Lab/QuickUMLS.git
```

which showed this error

```
ERROR: Cannot unpack file /tmp/pip-unpack-s1k8klso/QuickUMLS.git (downloaded from /tmp/pip-req-build-4f1w2qgm, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-req-build-4f1w2qgm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before creating an object of QuickUMLS make an import statement in your code:

from quickumls import QuickUMLS

matcher = QuickUMLS(quickumls_fp='/home/dileep/QuickUMLS')